# Remove Integer From List

Tags: list, function, haskell

I am trying to write a function in Haskell that will take a list of integers and if `m` is an element of that list, it will print the list without `m`, otherwise it will just print the list.  I have written

```
rmvFirst :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
rmvFirst m []                           = error "Empty"                     
rmvFirst m [x]       |    x == m        = error "Empty Set"
rmvFirst m (x:xs)    |    x == m        = (xs)
rmvFirst m (x:xs)    |    otherwise     = rmvFirst m (xs)
```

If I put in 3 [1..5], it outputs [4..5].  But, I want {1,2,4,5}.  The book I am using only has `min` and `max` defined.

Comment: In what language?

Comment: Why is an empty input or empty result an error? That's quite surprising! Also, what do you want to happen if there are several copies of `m` in the list?

Comment: @dfeuer Having an error on empty input might be meaningful in some contexts. I.e., you want to be sure that your function really removes an element -- if it does not, there's a bug somewhere else, so we might want to report that now. On the other end, the error on empty output is _really_ weird, I can't find any justification for that choice.

Comment: @dfeuer @chi I just wanted to get experience mixing different kinds of cases in the same function.  My choices are arbitrary.  If there are more than one `m` I only wish to remove the first instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @hugomg, your last case is wrong.

```
rmvFirst :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
rmvFirst m []                           = error "Empty"
rmvFirst m [x]       |    x == m        = error "Empty Set"
rmvFirst m (x:xs)    |    x == m        = (xs)
rmvFirst m (x:xs)    |    otherwise     = x : rmvFirst m (xs)
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is in the last case. You need to make sure that the `x` in the front of the list, which is not equal to `m`, is part of the list that you return.

Comment: I understand that's the problem.  What's the syntax for that?